# django-extra-views and SortableListMixin configuration confusion

Tags: django

I am using [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) in order to have sortable tables in my Django ListViews.

I'm not 100% sure of why I can't get it working, but I've always found working from tests.py difficult wrt templates.

So I have this in my views.py

```
class PartTypePartList(SortableListMixin, generic.ListView):
  model = PartNumber
  template_name = 'inventory/newparttype_list.html'
  sort_fields = ['name',]
  paginate_by = 25

  def get_queryset(self):
    self.parttype = self.kwargs['parttype']
    return PartNumber.objects.filter(fds_part_type=self.parttype)

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PartTypePartList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['parttype'] = self.parttype
    return context
```

And in urls.py

```
  url(r'^newparttype/(?P<parttype>\d{2})/$', views.PartTypePartList.as_view(), name='new_part_type_view'),
```

And with these two we are getting the list as expected.

In the relevant template:

```
  <a href="{{ request.path }}{{ sort_helper.get_sort_query_by_name }}">Name</a>
  <a href="{{ request.path }}{{ sort_helper.get_sort_query_by_name_asc }}">asc name</a>
  <a href="{{ request.path }}{{ sort_helper.get_sort_query_by_name_desc }}">desc name</a>
  {% if sort_helper.is_sorted_by_name %} ordered by name {{ sort_helper.is_sorted_by_name }} {% endif %}
```

The issue is that there is no sorting happening. In particular,

```
{{ sort_helper.get_sort_query_by_name }} and 
{{ sort_helper.get_sort_query_by_name_asc }} and
{{ sort_helper.get_sort_query_by_name_desc }}
```

each return an empty string.

What am I doing wrong?

I was using [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2) but the owner admitted he would not be continuing dev on it and I'm not skilled enough or time rich enough to take it on myself.

`[EDIT]`
I believe this still deserves a solution, but I've re-written the view to be a FBV rather than a CBV and am manipulating the data accordingly
`[/EDIT]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `get_queryset` parent method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    self.parttype = self.kwargs['parttype']

    qs = super(PartTypePartList, self).get_queryset()
    qs = qs.filter(fds_part_type=self.parttype)

    return qs
```